# PDO var_dump is getting false

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When I try to get the value from pdo statement, it's getting error, if I dump it, it shows false.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE student_id = :student_id and exam_no = :exam_no');
$student_id = $_POST['student_id'];
$academic_year = $_POST['academic_year'];
$exam_no = $_POST['exam_no'];

$stmt->bindParam(':student_id', $student_id);

$stmt->bindParam(':exam_no', $exam_no);

$stmt->execute();


$expr = $pdo->prepare('SELECT english FROM tbl WHERE student_id = :student_id and exam_no = :exam_no');
var_dump($expr);
```

Even if I use the query of $stmt in $expr, it's getting false.
Can't I use two pdo statements at the same time?

Comment: This is because there is not a single row in your result

Comment: @Dinistro If I replace query from $expr with $stmt's query, it's also getting false.

Comment: Didn't you need to call `execute`?

Comment: @Dinistro and actually, there is a single row in result

Comment: @Dinistro i can't execute, even i can't bindParam, it's getting:  Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam();

Comment: From the documentation: `If the database server cannot successfully prepare the statement, PDO::prepare() returns FALSE or emits PDOException (depending on error handling).` Run `$error = $pdo->errorInfo(); var_dump($error);`

Comment: @GeraldSchneider "Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute." didn't understand what does it mean

Comment: @GeraldSchneider i should use fetchAll() to $stmt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are not using all results from the previous query, so it is still active and blocking the new result. Add

```
$blah = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

before the new `prepare()` statement.